# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - default DISPLAY value

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I have noticed that `echo $DISPLAY` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS prints `:1` The same command on Ubuntu 16.04 prints `:0` Why it has been changed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For security reasons, and Wayland porting reasons, [GNOME] now launch the X server and Wayland server within the user's session, instead of starting one as root.
>
> The way that we do this is that we launch two X servers, one for the gdm greeter session, and for the session user.
>
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/910108/why-is-my-gdm-at-a-different-tty-than-my-desktop-environment

Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 supports running a Wayland session, even though it is not the default.